Surjective ring map concluded by "etale at a point"
Soergel claimed a surjective map in his proof of Lemma 3 of "Kategorie $\mathcal{O}$, perverse Garben und Moduln über den Koinvarianten zur Weylgruppe" (pdf). To describe this surjective map, we need some setup.
Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra with a triangulated decomposition $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{n}_{-}\oplus \mathfrak{h}\oplus \mathfrak{n}_{+}$, where $\mathfrak{h}$ is some Cartan subalgebra. Let $W$ be the Weyl group of root system of $\mathfrak{g}$. Denote by $Z$ the center of the enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. Consider the Harish-Chandra homomorphism $\eta: Z\rightarrow S(\mathfrak{h})$. Let $S_{+}$ be the maximal ideal of $S(\mathfrak{h})$ associated to $0\in\mathfrak{h}^{\ast}$. Now I can describe the surjective map claimed by Soergel:
Let $\rho$ be the half sum of positive roots. For a dominant regular weight $\lambda$, i.e. $\langle\lambda+\rho,\alpha^{\vee}\rangle\notin \mathbb{Z}^{\leq0}$ for all positive roots, there is a surjective morphism of rings induced by $\eta$
$$\overline{\eta}:Z\rightarrow S(\mathfrak{h})/S_{+}^{n}$$
where $n=|W_{[\lambda]}|$ and $W_{[\lambda]}$ is the integral Weyl group of $\lambda$.
(Observe that the right hand side is a local algebra of finite dimension.)
Indeed, Soergel first claimed a map $\xi$ is etale at weight $\lambda$ and concluded that $\overline{\eta}$ is surjective. I do not find the definition of $\xi$ in his paper and I guess $\xi$ is the quotient $\mathfrak{h}^{\ast}\rightarrow \mathfrak{h}^{\ast}/W$, where the $W$-action is the dot action. I think this may be a problem related to invariant theory. So which conclusions did the author use to conclude such a surjective map? Any references are appreciated.
